# is it possible to refer to javascript libraries from couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

In couchbase i write the views in javascript.  However as my views become more and more complex i need to share some javascript code by means of having libraries of javascript and referencing them (hopefully) from my map reducers.

is that thing possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to share code between views in Couchbase, because of the way views are stored internally. You can however have a look at [couchapp](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp), which allows you to insert Javascript code from different files into view maps. I think it uses [couchdbkit](http://couchdbkit.org/) for that.

**EDIT**

It appears that [Erica](https://github.com/benoitc/erica) has taken over from couchapp.